# ¿Cómo hacer que un botón abra una galería html?

Tags: html, html5

Tengo que hacer que un botón abra una galería desde la primera imagen. La galería está hecha con *fancybox*.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Identidad corporativa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body class="service">
    <button type="button" class="logos"></button>
    <div class="papel"></div>
    <div class="tarje"></div>
    <div class="folle"></div>
    <div class="carpe"></div>
    <div class="sobre"></div>
    <div class="revis"></div>
    <div class="cata"></div>
    <footer id="footserv"><b class="fuente2">Identidad Corporativa</b></footer>

    <div style="display:none;">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_1.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_1.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_2.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_2.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_3.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_3.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_4.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_4.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_5.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_5.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_6.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_6.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_7.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_7.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_8.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_8.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_9.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_9.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_10.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_10.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_11.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_11.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_12.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_12.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_13.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_13.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_14.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_14.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_15.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_15.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_16.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_16.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_17.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_17.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="img/galeria/gal_18.jpg" data-fancybox="galeria1"><img src="img/galeria/gal_18.jpg" alt="Galería" /></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

PD: No sé si es correcto ponerle el `display:none` al `div` que contiene la galería, tengo un conocimiento básico de *html*.

Answer (score 0):

Con `display:none;` dentro de una etiqueta Style, no haces absolutamente nada... se supone que la etiqueta style es para poder establecer un estilo css a esa etiqueta en concreto. Si lo que quieres es quitarle los bordes a ese div, debes crear una hoja css, establecer un identificador para ese div y escribir `border: none;`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres abrirlo con un boton, este deberia estar conectado a un link que te devuelva `JSON` **un petición Ajax** e imprimirlo en el documento, y al final recien aplicar el `fancybox`

```js
function click(){
$.ajax({
  url:'servidor',
  type:'GET',
  data:{coleccion:c},
  success: function(r){
    for(var i=0;i<r.length;i++){
      $("#galeria").append("<li><a href='img/galeria/gal_1.jpg' class= 'fancy-galeria'><img src='img/galeria/gal_1.jpg' alt="Galería" /></a></li>");
    }
    $("#galeria").append("<script>$('.fancy-galeria').fancybox({});</script>");
  }
});
}
```

```html
<div id='galeria'>
</div>
```